# After Nvidia driver installs, system reboots to blank screen on laptop

Tags: nvidia

I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in that way so no big deal I lost the GUI login. When I type # /etc/init.d/gdm3 start if says failed.
I have followed two different ideas on what would/should work but have had no luck.

- Asus N551VW
- Intel® Core™ i7 6700HQ Processor
- Chipset: Intel® HM170 Chipset
- Memory

  - RAM: 16GB
  - Samsung 8192 MB X2 (DDR4-2137)- P/N:   M471A1G43DB0-CPB
- Graphics:

  - Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
  - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M (GM107)  4096MB @  405 MHz
- Storage:

  - 1TB 5400 RPM With 128 G SSD
  - KINGSTON RBU-SMSM151S3128GD1
  - Seagate ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
  - SanDisk Ultra II
  - SDSSDHII-240G
- BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. N551VW.203 (09/18/2015)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is blacklisting the `nouveau` driver if you want to use the nvidia one.

To do that you would need to add

```
blacklist nouveau
```

to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Reboot and see if that helped you out.

Comment: I tried that nothing  help

Comment: Then probably something went wrong during your installation. Better purge every nvidia package you installed and then reinstall the neccessary ones.